# where to place this form tag

Tags: php, html

Below is code on how the file input and question number is added in each row:

```
var qnum = 1;

function insertQuestion(form) {   


    var $tbody = $('#qandatbl > tbody'); 
    var $tr = $("<tr class='optionAndAnswer' align='center'></tr>");
    var $qid = $("<td class='qid'>" + qnum + "</td>");
    var $image = $("<td class='image'></td>");


            var $imagefile = $('<input />')
        .attr({
            type: 'file',
            name: 'imageFile',
            class: 'imageFile'
        });

        $image.append($imagefile);

            var $imageclear = $('<input />')
        .attr({
            type: 'button',
            name: 'imageClear',
            class: 'imageClear',
            value: 'Clear File'
        });

        $image.append($imageclear);


    $tr.append($qid);
    $tr.append($image);   
    $tbody.append($tr); 

}
```

Below is the table where the table rows are added into:

```
<form id="enter" action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm(this);" >


<div id="details">
<table id="qandatbl" align="center">
<thead>
<tr>
    <th class="qid">Question No</th>
    <th class="image">Image</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody></tbody>
</table>
</div>

</form>
```

What I want to know is where do I put this code below so I can get started on checking files on server side? I can't replace the current  tag I have because I need that form tag.

```
   <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="uploader.php" method="POST"> 

$fileType = $_FILES['imageFile']['type'];

if (!in_array($fileType, $allowedImageTypes)) { 
    echo "Unsupported file type";
}
else
{
    // Process the file
}
```

Comment: You can't have two form tags for a single form...

Comment: If you can't have 2 form tags then where do I place this php code I have put in my edit of question which checks file type?

Comment: Do I only need to include the enctype tag in my original form tag and put php in same page?

Comment: thanks, if you want to put that in answer then i will mark it as best answer if you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have two form tags for the same form. Instead, add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to your existing `<form>` tag, and add the processing logic in your existing form's processing logic.